# How to use dictionaries with variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python program to automatically sort jobs that I'm working on. So far I have managed to create a dictionary.
For example:

```
monday = ('1' : 'clean the counters')
```

and assign everyone a number:

```
joe = random.randint(1,3)
```

but when I try:

```
print ("Today Joe has to do the", monday[joe]")
```

it spits out the errors.

Is there a better way to do this or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You must use dictionaries not tuples like this monday = {'1' : 'clean the counters'} and then convert joe variable to string.

Comment: `'1'` is a string.  `random.randint(1,3)` returns an integer.  So if your dictionary includes the keys `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'` you're never going to find them with integer keys.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra quotation mark that would cause an error.  You also need to convert the integer you assign to joe to be a `char`/`string`, since that is how it's stored in dictionary key.

A better way would be to just make the dictionary a list.  Using `1`, `2`, `3` in `char`/`string` form is just adding an unnecessary level of lookup.

For example:

```
Monday = ["clean the counters", "wash the floor", "take out the trash"]
joe = random.randint(0, 2)  # or joe = random.randint(0, Monday.length)
print("Today Joe has to do the", Monday[joe])`
```

Comment: Nice job recognizing the keys were just masquerading as indices.

Comment: nice job. this is better than using a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code. Firstly, you should be using `{}` to define a dictionary, not `()`, like:

```
monday = {1 : 'clean the counters'}
```

Also, you'll notice that I took the quotations off of the `1`, because you cannot search a dictionary using the integer key that `randint` generates if all of your keys are strings.

Finally, when you print you probably want:

```
print ("Today Joe has to " + monday[joe])
```

because the way you had it will not produce a normal sentence.

Comment: Sorry the i missed the typo, just realized the quotation error thanks!

Comment: @CharlesConrad No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modifications to your code and it should work:

```
monday = {'1' : 'clean the counters', '2' : 'upload the files', '3' : 'pick up the garbage'}
joe = str(random.randint(1, 3))
print("Today joe has to do : " + monday[joe])
```

Comment: I think it's better to "intify" the keys than to "stringify" the random int.  @matt.condit has it best of all and just gets rid of the whole dictionary.